# If statement inside parenthesis changes the value in a vector

Tags: c++

I have a following problem.

I have two vectors correct_data_labels.label and data_labels.label , label is the `vector<int >` whereas data_labels and correct_data_labels are the instance of my class.

I have a method where I have if statement inside it. When I use IF statement, the argument that I used inside the parenthesis does an arithmetic and changes the value. As seen in the code below: When I run the code it replaces the value written inside an IF statement. So `data_labels.label[row]` is replaced by `correct_data_labels.label[row]`

```
unsigned int num=0;
double percentage=0.00;

 for(register unsigned int row=0;row<data_labels.label.size();row++)
 {
     if((data_labels.label[row]=correct_data_labels.label[row]))
     {
         num=num+1;
     }
 }

 percentage = (num/data_labels.label.size());
```

This code is written in c++, I suppose other programming paradigms can answer the above query too.

Comment: Compile with higher warning level.

Comment: What is *the question* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the assignment operator `=` instead of the equality operator `==`. You probably got a warning about it which is why you have an extra set of parenthesis around the expression: `suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value` (on my compiler at least)

Replace `=` with `==` to do the comparison instead of the assignment.

Comment: long hours of programming made me forget a difference between operators.. Thanks..